# Accidentally deleted files too big for recycling bin

Tags: data-recovery

I've made a very large mistake. I've deleted some files accidentally from my C:// It was a bunch of .CR2 wedding photos that I mistaken for incorrectly exported JPEG's.

The files were too big to send to the recycling bin though. What can I do to recover the files? It was on an SSD, so I'm worried about that too.

I do have a backup on my compact flash + SD that I can use, although I have some duplicated .tiffs that I've retouched, removed bushes etc.

Any advice would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried running data recovery tools ?

Comment: Stop using the PC or risk Overwriting the file(s), once they are overwritten no recovery software can help recover them, Recovery should be done from an Image of the hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

Only option is recovery software. I have good experience with https://www.piriform.com/recuva 
It's best not to do anything else on that computer until you attempt the recovery, this minimizes the chance of files being overwritten.

This is the fastest way to use Recuva: https://www.piriform.com/docs/recuva/recuva-quick-start/quick-start-recovering-files-of-a-specific-type-(or-in-a-specific-location)

> 1. Start Recuva in Wizard mode. If the Wizard doesn't appear, click the Options button, and then click Run Wizard.
> 2. On the Welcome to the Recuva Wizard page, click Next.
> 3. On the File Type page, select the type of files you want to recover, then click Next. If you're not sure what type of files you're
>      looking for, select Other.
> 4. On the File Location page, select the location where you want to search, and then click Next.
> 5. On the Thank You page, click Start. Recuva displays the progress of the scan, and then shows its search results in the main window. If
>      the file(s) you're looking for aren't in the list, see below. Select
>      the check boxes beside the file or files you want to restore. The
>      color of the dot next to the file name indicates your chances for a
>      successful recovery (green for excellent, orange for acceptable, and
>      red for unlikely):
> 6. Click Recover. Select a destination for the recovered files (ideally, on another drive). Click OK.
>
> If Step 5 did not locate the files you were seeking, close Recuva and
>   run Steps 1 to 4 again. On the Thank You page, select Enable Deep Scan
>   and then click Start. This advanced scan will take much longer
>   (possibly hours).

Comment: Will this work with SSD's? As its flash memory I wonder if the data is permanently erased as It doesn't work like a HDD

Comment: I've had issues with older SSDs and recovering files, but I'm talking late 2008 model. Recuva just look at NTFS stuff, doesn't matter what storage technology is used.

Comment: What if installing Recuva overwrites the files you are trying to recover?